# Corona SDK - Use higher resolution images first in dynamic image resolution

Tags: android, coronasdk

In Corona SDK, one can have different resolutions for different devices using dynamic image resolution, modifying config.lua and adding images with the corresponding suffixes. While this system makes sense for iOS where there are a small number of resolutions to support, Android has many resolutions to support, and lower resolution graphics look blurry when scaled on higher resolution devices.

Is it possible to have Corona SDK select higher resolution images first in their dynamic image resolution system to ensure that Android users don't get a blurry app? I know that it is not the default behavior to conserve memory, but I'm targeting higher end devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, DON'T do that (loading higher-res first), because some devices cannot handle it (not because lack of memory, but lack of GPU capacity to handle big images), and you will have some nasty issues.

What you need to do is change the thresholds for your high-res graphics, instead of using the defaults.

Here are my config.lua relevant part, so you can get what I am saying

```
content = {
    width = 307,
    height = 512, 
    scale = "letterBox",
    fps = 60,

    imageSuffix = {
        ["@2"] = 1.42857143, -- note I am not using 2 here
        ["@4"] = 4,
    },
```

The reason why I went with 1.42 is that was the number I found to make the most number of Android phones load the @2 image instead of @1 without hitting memory or GPU issues.